# Salesforce - Edit polymorphic lookup by id

Tags: salesforce

I need update polymorphic lookup field by id. I use Bulk API v48.0. If I upload data to job (for example, for updating Event object)

```
id,Lead:Who.Id
00U5f000008eventId,00Q5f000003ISwhoId
```

then event is not updated and API return job status

```
{
  "id": "7505f000002pnjobId",
  "operation": "upsert",
  "object": "Event",
  "createdById": "0055f0000032userId",
  "createdDate": "2021-12-08T11:06:29.000+0000",
  "systemModstamp": "2021-12-08T11:06:51.000+0000",
  "state": "JobComplete",
  "externalIdFieldName": "Id",
  "concurrencyMode": "Parallel",
  "contentType": "CSV",
  "apiVersion": 48.0,
  "jobType": "V2Ingest",
  "lineEnding": "LF",
  "columnDelimiter": "COMMA",
  "numberRecordsProcessed": 1,
  "numberRecordsFailed": 1,
  "retries": 0,
  "totalProcessingTime": 62,
  "apiActiveProcessingTime": 3,
  "apexProcessingTime": 0
}
```

If I fill email instead id

```
id,Lead:Who.Email
00U5f000008eventId,test@mail.com
```

then event is successfully updated.

How can I update polymorphic lookup value by object id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're updating the value of the lookup field itself, you don't need to use the polymorphic relationship syntax. Simply refer to the field by its name, `WhoId`:

`Id,WhoId`